# Binding files in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to bind two files into one file ? If its possible how ?

E.g if i got two files a.exe and b.exe then i want to bind them into c.exe so when i execute c.exe it'll automatically execute a.exe and b.exe

Thank

Answer (score 4):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As far I know it is not possible to bind to compiled assemblies into one. But you could package them into a WINRAR executable archive as an installer.
Heres the idea although lousy it is viable,

you have a.exe, b.exe and c.exe

add all three to a Winrar archive and configure it so that c.exe is executed after the package is extracted so c.exe can execute a.exe and b.exe

like so

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("a.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("b.exe");
```

Comment: let me know if you want help on how to do that with Winrar.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply import the exe as a resource of your program,then dump it's data to a file and execute it.

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5695025/2734262) that may help you.